# Array con imágenes PHP en script

Tags: php, javascript, array

Comunidad estoy con el siguiente inconveniente: Quisiera imprimir imágenes de forma aleatoria(array creado en PHP) cada X segundos en un script con setTimeout. La función es la siguiente:

```
<?php $pic = array('image_1.jpg','image_2.jpg','image_3.jpg');
shuffle($pic); ?>
<?php for($i = 0, $i < 1, $i++) echo "<li style=\"display: flex;\"><img src=\"$pic[$i]\" width=\"250\" height=\"250\"></li>"; ?>
```

En base a ello, ¿cómo le hago?
Gracias

Comment: Luego de imprimirse las `N` imágenes, ¿el bucle debería repetirse? o siempre es aleatorio (_siendo que puede ser que siempre salga la misma imagen_)

Comment: puedes poner el array como una respuesta y hacer una consulta cada X segundos a través de ajax para poder consultar el arreglo

Comment: Podrias cambiar el numero que esta en el nombre de la imagen por un numero aleatorio... generado por random_int(1, 9) de php, asi las imagenes cambiarian de nombre cada que se haga el refresh.

Comment: El bucle es aleatorio (hay como 15 imágenes, pero no importa que 1 o 2 imágenes ser repitan varias veces) eso lo dejé apropósito. Ahora bien, con lo que sugiere Sr1871, voy a investigar eso. Aún así, con setTimeout no hay posibilidad de imprimir el array?

Comment: @Sr1871 Gracias colega, pude resolver dicho problema empleando ajax y JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

este es mi sugerencia:

```
<?php

$pic = array('image_1.jpg','image_2.jpg','image_3.jpg');

// Si hay muchas imágenes, sería posible usar scandir()
// para leer nombres de imágenes automáticamente y
// obtenerlos en un "array".

shuffle($pic);

// Usa punto y coma en iniciar el bucle "for"
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pic); $i++)
{
  echo "<li style='display: flex'><img src='$pic[$i]' width='250' height='250'></li>";
}

?>
```